# Scala test object class matcher with inheritance

Tags: scala, scalatest

I would like to write a Scala test which checks the exact class of an object created with factory method.

```
class Base { }

class Derived extends Base { }

class TestSpec {
  test("test instance class") {

    val result = new Derived()

    // I want to check that result is exactly Derived type
    result should be a[Derived]
    result should not be a[Base]
  }
}
```

I'm looking for something to test if object returned from my factory method for specific parameters is always base class. So it would be something like this is C#:

```
public class Base { }
    public class Derived : Base { }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var baseObject = new Base();
            var derivedObject = new Derived();

            var baseResult = baseObject.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base));
            var derivedResult = derivedObject.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Base));

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Base is subclass of Base: {0}\nDerived is subclass of Base: {1}", baseResult, derivedResult));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm new in scala. Only what I found on Matchers is a[T] and an[T] but they not work as I'm expecting. I cannot find answer here.

Comment: You can probably compare `obj.getClass`, but it will not account for the type parameters because of the type erasure. (`List[String]` and `List[List[Int]]` are the same after erasure, AFAIK).

Answer (score 2):

you can do this :

```
    class A{}
    class B extends A{}

    val result = new B()
    result.getClass.getName shouldEqual classOf[B].getName
    result.getClass.getName.equals(classOf[A].getName) shouldBe false
```

Comment: Can you look please on my updated task description. Can I get information if class is subclass without checking class name?

Comment: If it's possible I don't know how, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`new Derived()` will always be an instance of `Base` as it inherits from `Base`, which means:

```
new Derived().isInstanceOf[Base]
```

will return true.

But the opposite is false: `Base` won't be an instance of `Derived`.

---

Thus, to check if it's the `Base` class (and not the `Derived` class), you can use these two combined conditions:

```
new Base() should not be a[Derived]
new Base() shouldBe a[Base]
```

and to check if it's the `Derived` class, the following is enough:

```
new Derived() shouldBe a[Derived]
```